# How would you convert a string of non-alphanumeric symbols into a string array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I was wondering how exactly one would convert a string of non-alphanumeric symbols into a string array. For example, what would be the code that takes the string

`"@%$!#& (&$#^"`

as an input, and converts it into a string array

`{"@", "%", etc}`

Comment: As such, this question is too broad, there are a lot of possible solutions. You should post some sample code that you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: Does it have to be `String[]`? You could use `string.getChars()`

Comment: Sorry. I attempted to use a String.split(); function but I was unsure of the delimiters to use.

Comment: you can split with delimiter

Answer (score 0):

Create a `String` array of the length of string..

```
int size = theString.length();
String[] asStringArray = new String[size];
```

then step through that array/`String` adding chars from the `String` with [charAt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int))

```
for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
  asStringArray[i] = ""+theString.charAt(i);
}
```

Other option is [substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))

```
  asStringArray[i] = theString.substring(i,i+1);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that solution does not work. The second last line of code is invalid, as you are adding characters to a string array.

Comment: Yikes, it works now :P